# HBase shell query rowkey coming from the result of a java method

Tags: shell, hash, hbase

My szenario is the rowkey of HBase table is hashed by some hash function, so it's not that transparent to use get with the rowkey to get the KV pairs.
I want to use java method in HBase shell to get the hash value, and then pass it to the get command in HBase shell, do I have this possibility? I.e. by using following statement 
get 'table_name', hash("String")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HBase directly doesn't support Custom UDFs But you can use custom UDFs in Phoenix : https://phoenix.apache.org/udf.html.

Phoenix is a SQL layer on top of HBase.  You can create a view or table in apache phoenix on top of HBase.